# Добавление слова в конец списка

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Имеется список строк. Имеется текстовое поле и кнопка.

```
<input type="text" id="dob"><input type="button" id="but_dob" value="Добавить">
```

Как сделать чтоб пользователь ввел слово и при нажатии на кнопку слово добавлялось в конец списка без перезагрузки страницы?
Сколько уже ломаю голову, но что-то ничего сообразить не могу...

Comment: что за список строк? код пожалуйста!..

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- подключаем jquery и свой файлик с функцией -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
<!-- делаем 2 текстовых поля -->    
    <input type="text" id="word1" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="word2" value="" />
    <input type="button" id="add_word">
```

functions.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_word").click(function(){
       fst = $("#word1").val();
       add = $("#word2").val();
       $("#word2").val(add+fst);
    });
});
```

на коленке за несколько минут, может, и не очень красиво. Но вариант работает.

Comment: Если в текстовое поле, то там не `$("#word2").val()` будет, а `("#word2").innerHTML`.

Comment: Не забудьте добавить return false; в конец события click, что бы не произошла перезагрузка страницы!

Comment: @kemerov4anin, только не $("#word2").innerHTML, а $("#word2").html('<здесь html, который нужно установить>')

Comment: ну, да... говорю же... "на коленке". В голове пока ещё смесь чистого javascript и jquery )) Спасибо @GLAGOLA за поправку

Answer (score 1):

Можно так вот) По нажатию кнопки вызываем функцию add(), в которой получаем содержимое div и содержимое текстового поля... После в div выводим то что хотим.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function add()
    {
        var my_div = document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML;
        var my_text = document.getElementById("my_text").value;
        my_div = my_div + " " + my_text;
        document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = my_div;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="my_text">
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="my_but" value="Add" onClick="add()">
    <br>
    <div id="my_div">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Примерный вариант)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function addWord(w){
    var el = document.createElement('span');
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(w));
    document.getElementById('wordlist').appendChild(el);
}
</script>

<input id="word"><input type="button" value="add word" onclick="addWord(document.getElementById('word').value);">
<div id="wordlist"></div>
```

Слова добавляются в span'ах, что позволяет задавать им стили или удалять их из списка.

Answer (score 1):

Проще, конечно, с jQuery, но не понятно, что за список. Но если это обычный список заключенный в `<div>`, то:

```
$("#form form").submit(function(){
      var text=$("#form input[name=txt]").val();
      $("#div_list").append(text+"<br />");      
      return false;
});
```

и

```
<div id="div_list">
</div>

<div id="form">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="txt"><input type="submit" value="Do That!">
  </form>
</div>
```